# How to implement wait() without passing the element in selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a scenario in my project where i need to wait for a file to process in the blackened,when i upload a file. Based on that success or failure is displayed.

Currently i am using Thread.sleep() as there is not element i could wait for.

Can you please suggest me is there any way to handle this.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It require either an flag in DB with stated that file is process successfully.
If you having such thing than connect to DB using JDBC and loop the record till the flag not change or record not found.

Another way is an API response, it may need developers to add an key in api response with you can validate using java library like rest-assured

Third - If that file you can see in UI after complete process then use loop till the element with filename is not shown on UI, make sure  loop should break at particular time period otherwise the loop run for indefinite time

Comment: Thanks Shubham, Tried the first option and it works.